# What is the difference between effect and attribute in Adobe Premiere?

Tags: adobe-premiere

What is the difference between effect and attribute in Adobe Premiere?

For example, when I open the tutorial  `TUTORIAL PROJECT Prepare Your Clips For Editing.prproj`  provided with  Adobe Premiere, I see that motion, capacity, and time remapping are listed as video effects:

[image]

However, when I right click on the video clip -> `Remove Attributes`, I see that  motion, capacity, and time remapping are listed as video attributes:

[image]

[image]

I use Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2018 on Microsoft Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT no

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thanks, I see, I think your answers is helpful! I can't see deleted questions or answers as I have below 10k reputation points on superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the two descriptions from the [vendor product support website](https://helpx.adobe.com/support/premiere-pro.html) (see below), my interpretation is that those effects you see in the tutorial are the [fixed effects](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/effects.html) you can apply to clips, and the [attributes](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/framemaker/2015/using/using-framemaker-2015/frm_structauth_sa/Attributes-.htm) which you see when you right-click a video clip are the effects which may be applied to that clip already. So the attributes seem to affect the effects of the clip elements.

> ### [About effects](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/effects.html)
>
> Premiere Pro includes a variety of audio and video effects that you
>   can apply to clips in your video program. An effect can add a special
>   visual or audio characteristic or provide an unusual feature
>   attribute.

---

> ### [Attributes](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/framemaker/2015/using/using-framemaker-2015/frm_structauth_sa/Attributes-.htm)
>
> Attributes supply additional information about an element.

---

### Further Proof Resource

- [Remove Attributes Not Working on Some Effects](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2264998)

  > I've used the Remove Attributes function in the past to remove effects
  >   off of multiple clips. Ever since the new Premiere Pro version, I'm
  >   unable to do that with the EQ (Obsolete) and Dynamics (Obsolete)
  >   effects. They're selected to be removed, but nothing happens.
  >
  > ---
  >
  > **Correct Answer**
  >
  > You should now be able to remove obsolete audio effects with Remove
  >   Attributes with the 11.0.2 update that was released today.